# What other values will generate error when given to std::minstd_rand::seed()?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I'm on VC++11, so far those values generate errors, but not on ideone.com

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
//int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //print_seq(seeded_rand(0x7fffffff,10));
    //cout << print_seq(seeded_rand(0xffffffff,10));
    ////print_seq(seeded_rand(0,10));
    //cout <<  print_seq(seeded_rand(-50000,10));
    //cout <<  print_seq(seeded_rand(1,10));

    minstd_rand r1;
    minstd_rand0 r2;

    r1.seed(0);
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Those values also generated errors

```
0xfffffffe
0x7fffffff
-2
0
```

what other values are supposed to generate an abort() call ?

[image: here is sceenshot]

visual C++ 11.0.61030.0 update 4

Comment: Please give us a [SSCCEE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I can't reproduce any problem with those values. There are no values that are "supposed" to cause `seed()` to throw an exception or abort your program.

Comment: done ! provided a screenshot and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **26.5.3.1/5** `explicit linear_congruential_engine(result_type s = default_seed);`
>   *Effects:* Constructs a `linear_congruential_engine` object. If `c mod m` is 0 and `s mod m` is 0, sets the engine’s state to 1, otherwise sets the engine’s state to `s mod m`.

For some reason, MSVC implementation chooses to assert in debug build when the "sets the engine’s state to 1" condition triggers; in release build, it just quietly seeds with 1 instead of 0.

`minstd_rand` is a typedef for `linear_congruential_engine<uint_fast32_t, 48271, 0, 2147483647>`. So any seed that is 0 modulo 2147483647 == 0x7FFFFFFF is meaningless (the generator would just produce a sequence of zeros, if it weren't adjusting the seed to 1 in this case).

Comment: `-2 == 0xFFFFFFFE == 0 (modulo 0x7FFFFFFF)`. Recall that `seed()` takes an unsigned integer as a parameter.

Comment: oh thanks, so -2 is just 0xffffffff-1 which is 2^32-2